# Having trouble with a C# Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I save my script, it comes up with these errors:

> Assets/Player Controller.cs(38,128): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type.

and this

> Assets/Player Controller.cs(38,129): error CS8032: Internal compiler error during parsing, Run with -v for details.

I have researched it, but no answer. can someone please help? the problem is on this line:

```
GUI.TextField (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 65, Screen.height / 2 - 11, 130, 22) "Do something to start"); }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a comma between the `Rect` and `string` arguments to the [`GUI.TextField(Rect, string)` constructor](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html).

Try this instead:

```
GUI.TextField (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 65, Screen.height / 2 - 11, 130, 22), "Do something to start"); }
```

Also, consider formatting across multiple lines to make the structure a bit clearer (and errors like this a bit easier to spot):

```
    GUI.TextField(
        new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 65, Screen.height / 2 - 11, 130, 22),
        "Do something to start");
}
```

Comment: "Write code that never forces the developer to scroll horizontally" is one of my big rules-of-thumb.

Comment: @UweKeim: Amen. My version of that rule-of-thumb: _What looks "nice" on  one or more big monitors in the office (which is itself dubious)...is a PITA on a notebook with a VPN connection at home!_

Comment: @UweKeim: I've grown to 150 over the years, but, yes, working through issues like this in Unix terminal emulators with no syntax highlighting teaches a lot of good, disciplined habits. :}